# Nullclines and equilibrium point labels

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to draw the vector field, nullclines, and equilibrium points for the system
$$
\begin{align*}
x'&=2x-y+3(x^2-y^2)+2xy\\
y'&=x-3y-3(x^2-y^2)+3xy
\end{align*}
$$

I have completed the following thus far:

```
f[x_, y_] = 2 x - y + 3 (x^2 - y^2) + 2 x y;
g[x_, y_] = x - 3 y - 3 (x^2 - y^2) + 3 x y;
vp = VectorPlot[{f[x, y], g[x, y]}, {x, -2, 4}, {y, -4, 2},
   VectorScale -> {0.045, 0.9, None},
   Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y},
   VectorPoints -> 16,
   VectorStyle -> {GrayLevel[0.8]}];
cp = ContourPlot[{f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0}, {x, -2, 4}, {y, -4, 2}];
ptRules = NSolve[{f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0}, {x, y}];
Show[vp, cp, 
 Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{x, y}] /. ptRules}]]
```

The resulting plot follows.

[image]

What would be the simplest way to add labels to each of the equilibrium points, perhaps by using the data stored in ptRules?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. One way

```
f[x_, y_] = 2 x - y + 3 (x^2 - y^2) + 2 x y;
g[x_, y_] = x - 3 y - 3 (x^2 - y^2) + 3 x y;
vp = VectorPlot[{f[x, y], g[x, y]}, {x, -2, 4}, {y, -4, 2}, 
 VectorScale -> {0.045, 0.9, None}, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
   VectorPoints -> 16, VectorStyle -> {GrayLevel[0.8]}];
cp = ContourPlot[{f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0}, {x, -2, 4}, {y, -4, 2}];
ptRules = NSolve[{f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0}, {x, y}];
Show[vp, cp, Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{x, y}] /. ptRules}],
 Graphics[Text[ToString[Round[#, .2]], #] & /@ ({x, y} /. ptRules)]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You could also make it such that if the mouse is moved over it, it will show the coordinates.

If you wanted the text larger and different color, Style can be used

```
Graphics[Text[Style[ToString[Round[#, .2]], 14, Blue], #] & /@ ({x, y} /. ptRules)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To make the text shift a little to make it more clear:

```
Graphics[Text[Style[ToString[Round[#, .2]], 12, Blue], #, 
   {1, 0}] & /@ ({x, y} /. ptRules)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update to add tooltip per comment below**

```
f[x_, y_] = 2 x - y + 3 (x^2 - y^2) + 2 x y;
g[x_, y_] = x - 3 y - 3 (x^2 - y^2) + 3 x y;
vp = VectorPlot[{f[x, y], g[x, y]}, {x, -2, 4}, {y, -4, 2}, 
 VectorScale -> {0.045, 0.9, None}, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
   VectorPoints -> 16, VectorStyle -> {GrayLevel[0.8]}];
cp = ContourPlot[{f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0}, {x, -2, 4}, {y, -4, 2}];
ptRules = NSolve[{f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0}, {x, y}];

Show[vp,
 cp,
 Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], 
    Tooltip[ Point[{x, y}], Round[{x, y}, .2]] /. ptRules}]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. I learn again. Can you show me how to get the points to show up when you hover the mouse above them?

Comment: @David  added tooltip

Comment: For anyone that is interested in using the `Module` function please see my addon: `phase2eq[a1_, b1_] := Module[{}, f[x_, y_] = a1; g[x_, y_] = b1; vp = VectorPlot[{f[x, y], g[x, y]}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, VectorScale -> {0.045, 0.9, None}, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, VectorPoints -> 16, VectorStyle -> {GrayLevel[0.8]}]; cp = ContourPlot[{f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]; ptRules = NSolve[{f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0}, {x, y}]; Show[vp, cp, Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Tooltip[Point[{x, y}], Round[{x, y}, .2]] /. ptRules}]]]`

Comment: @FieldofNodes I've moved your answer to the comment because it was just a duplicate of Nasser's and the Module addition is not relevant for this question.